# Highlighting Devx GridView through java script

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a Devx AspxGridView and i want to highlight few rows of it on conditional basis.
For eg. If user selects Vendor from a drop down ,then Vendor details shown in GridView must be highlighted or else if he selects Supplier..then those details must be highlighted.
I want to do this on Drop down selection through java script.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript, why not use the built-in functionality of the control itself? You should look at

1. [Implement Conditional Formatting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3779)
2. [ASPxGridView.HtmlDataCellPrepared Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_HtmlDataCellPreparedtopic)

Hope that helps. Let us know.

Comment: Ok.Actually i have got a huge data for Suppliers and Vendors and i populate this details in a drop down using Page Method.